# VML Being stripped from sends

Tags: marketing-cloud, email

I have an icon constructed similarly to the bulletproof buttons concepts. I can load the html into an email in my outlook client and send it to myself with no issue.

Sending via test send in ExactTarget does... something. I still get the text from inside the icon, but the icon is otherwise not visible:

```
<!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <v:roundrect style="height:20px;width:20px;position:relative;top:5px;" arcsize="50%" strokeweight="2px" strokecolor="#FFFFFF" fillcolor="#ffcb05">
        <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
            <center style="font:300 14px/15px Impact, Sans-serif;color:#FFFFFF;mso-line-height-rule:exactly;">!</center>
        </v:textbox>
    </v:roundrect>
    <v:rect style="width:20px;height:1px;" stroke="f">
        <v:fill opacity="0" color="#FFF" ></v:fill>
    </v:rect>
<![endif]-->
```

HTML/VML icon in outlook from outlook: [image: Icon1]

HTML/VML icon in outlook from ExactTarget: [image]

Comment: I would not recommend render testing from a Send Preview test send.  They are fraught with issues in SFMC.   The best way I've found is to configure a test audience (DE or List) and do a Guided Send to the audience.   Please do that to see if that changes the outcome.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Over thousands of tests sent using triggered sends, guided sends, and test sends, I have never seen any difference in the resulting HTML.

Comment: Send Preview tests have issues in evaluating AMPScript, send from a non-SAP IP and can contain bad header/footer code despite the Delivery Profile setting below the audience.  Use it if you want, but there are certainly scenarios where it jacks with responsive email code -- showing one way in the Send Preview send and another in a Guided/UI/Trigger send.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to tell Outlook to expect VML in my ExactTarget template:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
```

Comment: Please delete this answer and revise your question.

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Why would I do that? VML wasn't displaying, this is why. Problem and solution.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't sound like an answer to the question.